# TI Sensortag iBeacon support

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

It seems TI have removed iBeacon support from the Sensortag.

How do I get hold of a copy of the older (pre V1.5) of the SensorTag firmware that supports iBeacon and a copy of the iPhone App to configure the iBeacon settings (again, it seems TI has removed SensorTag iBeacon settings from their BLE Multitool IOS App and the TI SensorTag IOS App).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, now the sensorTags are no more interesting for independent developers, because you have to apply for the MFi program at Apple and you have to create a paid coface account. This is not really possible for private iOS developers and get even worse, if you are outside of the US.

One possibility could be, that someone could upload an older .ipa file of the sensorTag app, that have the iBeacon firmware included. But I didn't find anyone, which can upload this older *.ipa or at least the related firmwares from this ipa. :(

If anyone has a solution for this, please report it here (or via private message). Otherwise the sensorTag is useless.

Comment: I'm exactly on the same boat. Did you find a different solution to this? Maybe using a different prototyping board?

Comment: Yes, I found a solution for this. I've got an iBeacon enabled firmware from another user. I can also provide it to you, but note here, there is no private message feature on stack overflow.

Comment: Well, do you want to share it on Dropbox, or maybe push it to a github repo?

Answer (score 2):

The iBeacon code was removed because Apple requires users to sign an iBeacon license agreement to get access to the SensorTag iBeacon code. You can request access and find more information on the SensorTag page: www.ti.com/sensortag

Jarle Boe

Texas Instruments

Comment: Can I use Sensortag as iBeacon on Android?

Answer (score -1):

It appears that even if you do sign the Apple license for MFi there is no longer a download for the firmware to activate the iBeacon in a SensorTag - at least that resource is not evident on http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_with_iBeacon